# Error Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo when debugging Visual Studio

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, smo

I have this crazy issue where a SMO operation is failing

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=14.1.17283.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'. Acceso denegado.

I am using the Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects nuget package with version 140.17283.0

I am using Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.42